# Написать валидный конфиг Nginx

Tags: nginx, роутинг

Имеется api с root /var/www/esn/web/index.php и так же имеется страница с root /var/www/esn-frontend/build/index.html.

Задача: разрулить Nginx так, чтобы по ссылке sitename.com/ на одном и том же домене(без использования поддоменов) он отдавал страницу /var/www/esn-frontend/build/index.html, а по урлу sitename.com/api отдавал /var/www/esn/web/index.php.
Испробовал несколько вариантов, но не один не дал желаемого результата.

```
 server{
    listen 8800;
    server_name 46.101.117.134;

    location / {
            root /var/www/esn-frontend/build/;
            index index.html;
    }

    location /api {
            root /var/www/esn/web;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                try_files $uri =404;
            }
    }
}
```

Руководствовался следующими статьями(а так же документацией):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082831/nginx-configuration-with-multiple-location-blocks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40147326/nginx-location-with-root-in-other-directory-and-php
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033362/two-document-roots-with-nginx-and-fastcgi

Comment: Нужен конфиг. Хотя бы нерабочий

Comment: Прикрепил нерабочий конфиг